# Programmatically created textbox isn't showing Text, assigned in code-behind, retrieved from DB

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I have a form in asp.net which looks like this:

1. Less than one year
2. `Age in years[]____________`

1,2 are radiobuttonlist, with 2 I've a textbox which takes the input if #2 is selected.
This form is saving alright, but I'm having trouble when I'm trying to show the results.

I have created these radiobuttonlist and textbox in code-behind. Now when I am trying to show the answers, I am creating these controls again in Gridview.rowDatabound and retrieving their value from database using a sqlDataReader. The code looks like this:

```
            Dim txtOther As New TextBox
            txtOther.ID = "txtOther"

            Dim strOtherTxt As String = "Why the **** this isn't working"


            fillResponse(rdoLstOption, txtChildID.Text, intQuestionID, strOtherTxt)

            txtOther.Text = strOtherTxt

            e.Row.Cells(2).Controls.AddAt(0, rdoLstOption)
            e.Row.Cells(2).Controls.AddAt(1, txtOther)
```

And the fillResponse looks like this: (here I am checking whether it's a radiobutton or a checkbox list - my checkBoxList isn't working either)

```
        con.Open()
        Dim rdr As SqlDataReader
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If typeCtrlType.Name = "RadioButtonList" Then
            fillRdoBtnList(ctrlToFill, rdr, strOtherText)
        ElseIf typeCtrlType.Name = "CheckBoxList" Then
            fillChckBoxList(ctrlToFill, rdr)
        End If
        con.Close()
```

And finally fillRdoBtnList looks like this:

```
Private Sub fillRdoBtnList(ByRef rdoBtnListToFill As RadioButtonList, rdr As SqlDataReader, ByRef strOtherTxt As String)
    While rdr.Read()
        rdoBtnListToFill.SelectedValue = rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("fkLuAnswerID"))
        If Not rdr.IsDBNull(rdr.GetOrdinal("strOtherTxt")) Then
            strOtherTxt = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("strOtherTxt"))
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

I am getting the string I am expecting in strOtherTxt, but it just doesn't appear in my form! I have debugged my program and I found that txtOther. Text is getting the right Text but even then it won't appear on my form!

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think it had something to do with the viewstate. Earlier I was databinding the selected value to checkbox on PostBack. But now I am taking the input in separate page and sending the value into my "checkboxlist page". That fixed the problem.

I am still confused though what was happening here. Any explanation would be appreciated.